# PHP get server protocol after URL redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess

There are lots of similar topics on SOF but non of them seemed to answer the specific problem that I am facing. I am using the below function to identify the server protocol (http/https).

```
public static function srvProto() {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) &&
        ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1) ||
        isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) &&
        $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
    {
        return 'https';
    }
    return 'http';
}
```

It works great. The problem is if my origin request comes with `http` the above function returns `http`. However, I have a url rewrite in my .htaccess that redirects all `http` requests into `https`.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain/$1 [R,L]
```

After the url rewrite I want to identify the protocol of the new URL not the original one. How, do I do this ?

**UPDATE**

vardump of my $_SERVER :

```
[PATH] => /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin 
[TEMP] => /tmp 
[TMP] => /tmp 
[TMPDIR] => /tmp 
[HTTP_ACCEPT] =>     text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8 
[HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate, sdch 
[HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.8 
[HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive 
[CONTENT_LENGTH] => 0 
[HTTP_COOKIE] => xxx
[HTTP_HOST] => mydomain.ca 
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0)     AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36 
[HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1 
[REDIRECT_UNIQUE_ID] => WEnRak32qKIAB-L565AAAABG 
[REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200 
[UNIQUE_ID] => WEnRak32qKIAB-L565AAAABG 
[SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache 
[SERVER_NAME] => mydomain.ca 
[SERVER_ADDR] => 77.0.0.0
[SERVER_PORT] => 80 
[REMOTE_ADDR] => 206.223.191.106 
[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/mydomain/public_html 
[REQUEST_SCHEME] => http 
[CONTEXT_PREFIX] => 
[CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/mydomain/public_html 
[SERVER_ADMIN] => webmaster@mydomain.ca 
[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /home/mydomain/public_html/admin/default.php 
[REMOTE_PORT] => 53936 
[REDIRECT_URL] => /admin/dashboard 
[REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING] => controller=dashboard 
[SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1 [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET 
[QUERY_STRING] => controller=dashboard 
[REQUEST_URI] => /admin/dashboard 
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /admin/default.php 
[PHP_SELF] => /admin/default.php 
[REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1481232746.157 
[REQUEST_TIME] => 1481232746
```

Comment: well if all traffic is redirected to https. there is nothing to detect there, you already know

Comment: Is this like an OCD feature where you check whether or not you were redirected from http to https? What is the purpose of what you're trying... maybe knowing what that is, people may help you more specifically on the issue you're facing.

Comment: That URL rewrite will cause a totally separate second request, with the HTTPS protocol properly detected. If it isn't being detected, something else entirely is going on (like a proxy/config that isn't setting `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` or `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']` correctly).

Comment: If `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` is set (and equals to `on`), then you're on HTTPS. Otherwise it's HTTP. Easy as that, no need to check for more.

Comment: @Dagon I have the same code base into multiple sites in different servers. We dont force https in all servers. The function on the question works perfectly where I dont have the url rewrite added.

Comment: @ceejayoz can you suggest me anything that I may try to figure out ?

Comment: on the site that this fails, can you update the question with the results for `print_r($_SERVER)`

Comment: @Dagon please check my update

Comment: What is your Apache version?